# CSS rules behaving differently in IE7 and IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've got a strange issue with IE7 and IE8 where drop-down menu items jump around when hovered over - some negative margin rules are being applied on hover on the top level menu items which are cascading down to sub-menu items. Basically the drop-down menu is overriding some of the styles from Twitter bootstrap, which is included before the *app.css* applies custom styles.

This code is the culprit and I can't seem to override it without losing the styling on the top level items that I need:

```
.navbar .nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar .nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar .nav > li.active > a,
.navbar .nav li.dropdown.open > .dropdown-toggle {
    height: 12px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Here is a [demo link][1] (only the dropout menu styling is the issue at the moment, I realise the top level items aren't very legible!)

Comment: To make sure: I see jumping behavior on all browsers I've so far tried (Chrome, IE9, Firefox). When IE9 runs in compability mode the difference I see is the higher `div.wrapper`. Is that the issue, the increased height? Or is it the jumping that I see everywhere?

Comment: The jumping behaviour I mean is within the megamenu - on the section title and subsection links, not on the main menu bar itself - which I now see and I think you are meaning. The issue I'm referring to only happens in IE7 and 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the rule to this (basically add the descendent selector under `.nav`):

```
.navbar .nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar .nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar .nav > li.active > a,
.navbar .nav > li.dropdown.open > .dropdown-toggle {
    height: 12px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

i.e.

```
.navbar .nav li.dropdown.open > .dropdown-toggle {
```

becomes:

```
.navbar .nav > li.dropdown.open > .dropdown-toggle {
```

Comment: many thanks, think i need to get a better grip of using descendants